# RecyclerView crashes upon launching app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I recently started android development. I started to work with RecyclerViews. However after following a tutorial I got it to work. But after adding more information to it, it began to crash. I can't seem to figure it out and hopefully the experienced users of these site can help me.

Crash Log

```
        07-18 02:19:23.376  12975-12975/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
    07-18 02:19:23.717  12975-12982/com.austinerck.projectteamwork I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2838(236KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 28% free, 807KB/1135KB, paused 8.003ms total 31.172ms
    07-18 02:19:23.855  12975-12982/com.austinerck.projectteamwork I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 589(76KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 51% free, 954KB/1978KB, paused 6.145ms total 48.881ms
    07-18 02:19:23.866  12975-12998/com.austinerck.projectteamwork D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
    07-18 02:19:23.870  12975-12975/com.austinerck.projectteamwork D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c54ad0, tid 12975
    07-18 02:19:23.884  12975-12975/com.austinerck.projectteamwork D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
    07-18 02:19:23.946  12975-12998/com.austinerck.projectteamwork D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c54dc0, tid 12998
    07-18 02:19:23.961  12975-12998/com.austinerck.projectteamwork I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    07-18 02:19:23.967  12975-12998/com.austinerck.projectteamwork D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
    07-18 02:19:23.979  12975-12998/com.austinerck.projectteamwork W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    07-18 02:19:23.979  12975-12998/com.austinerck.projectteamwork W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6cb5ce0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    07-18 02:19:24.071  12975-12975/com.austinerck.projectteamwork I/art﹕ Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 122(17KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 998KB/1978KB, paused 1.563ms total 17.553ms
    07-18 02:19:24.095  12975-12975/com.austinerck.projectteamwork I/art﹕ Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 39(2256B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 996KB/2020KB, paused 1.319ms total 19.319ms
    07-18 02:19:24.130  12975-12975/com.austinerck.projectteamwork I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 13(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 984KB/2008KB, paused 3.235ms total 25.851ms
    07-18 02:19:24.133  12975-12975/com.austinerck.projectteamwork I/art﹕ Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 71MB allocation
    07-18 02:19:24.151  12975-12975/com.austinerck.projectteamwork I/art﹕ Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 984KB/2008KB, paused 1.061ms total 18.133ms
    07-18 02:19:24.157  12975-12975/com.austinerck.projectteamwork E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM"
    07-18 02:19:24.158  12975-12975/com.austinerck.projectteamwork D/skia﹕ --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
    07-18 02:19:24.158  12975-12975/com.austinerck.projectteamwork D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    07-18 02:19:24.159  12975-12975/com.austinerck.projectteamwork E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.austinerck.projectteamwork, PID: 12975
        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                at com.austinerck.projectteamwork.ProjectsListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ProjectsListActivity.java:104)
                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4121)
                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3431)
                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1810)
                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1306)
                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:523)
                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1988)
                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
                at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:562)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
                at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:493)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                at android.view.Choreographer$Fram
```

ProjectsListActivity.java

```
package com.austinerck.projectteamwork;

import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ProjectsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_projects_list);

        //Creates objects for RecyclerView
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.projects_list_recyclerview);


        //Create layout manager for RecyclerView
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ProjectsListAdapter());


        //Sets up SwipeRefreshLayout
        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.projects_list_swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                //TODO: Refresh code here
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_green_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_dark,
                android.R.color.holo_red_dark);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_projects_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch(id){
            case R.id.action_sort:
                Shortcut.toast(this,"Coming Soon");
                break;
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                //TODO: Refresh code here
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Shortcut.toast(this,"Coming Soon");
                break;
            case R.id.action_feedback:
                Shortcut.toast(this,"Coming Soon");
                break;
            case R.id.action_help:
                Shortcut.toast(this,"Coming Soon");
                break;
            default:
                Shortcut.toast(this,"ERROR: Unknown Action");
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

class ProjectsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    ArrayList<ProjectDetails> projectDetails = new ArrayList<>();

    public ProjectsListAdapter(){
        //Sets values in projectDetails
        projectDetails.add(new ProjectDetails(NasaProjects.GEMINI));
        projectDetails.add(new ProjectDetails(NasaProjects.APOLLO));
        projectDetails.add(new ProjectDetails(NasaProjects.ISS));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        //Gets the view as an object
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_projects_card, viewGroup, false);

        //Gets TextViews as objects to pass them to ProjectsListView
        /*TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.project_detail_name);
        TextView owner = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.project_detail_owner);
        TextView desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.project_detail_desc);*/

        return new ProjectsListView(view/*, name, owner, desc*/);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        ProjectsListView view = (ProjectsListView) viewHolder;
        /*view.name.setText(projectDetails.get(i).getName());
        view.owner.setText(projectDetails.get(i).getOwner());
        view.desc.setText(projectDetails.get(i).getDesc());*/

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return projectDetails.size();
    }

    class ProjectsListView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View view;
        //TextView name, owner, desc;

        public ProjectsListView(View view/*, TextView name, TextView owner, TextView desc*/){
            super(view);
            this.view = view;
            /*this.name = name;
            this.owner = owner;
            this.desc = desc;*/
        }

    }
}

class ProjectDetails{

    private String name, owner, desc;

    public ProjectDetails(NasaProjects nasaProjects){
        name = nasaProjects.getName();
        owner = nasaProjects.getOwner();
        desc = nasaProjects.getDesc();

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
}
```

activity_projects_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ProjectListActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/projects_list_swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/projects_list_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/material_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/material_margin"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

fragment_projects_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/material_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/material_padding"
    android:elevation="@dimen/material_elevation"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/material_corner_radius">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/projects_list_item_background"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/material_padding_border"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/material_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/material_padding"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/material_padding">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/project_detail_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/material_title_size"
                android:textColor="@color/material_title_color"
                android:text="Title goes here"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/project_detail_owner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/material_subtitle_size"
                android:textColor="@color/material_subtitle_color"
                android:text="Subtitle here"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/material_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/material_padding_border"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/material_padding">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/project_detail_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/material_content_size"
                android:textColor="@color/material_content_color"
                android:text="Hello World! If you are seeing this text an error must of occured!"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: This is an out of memory error. what is your **projects_list_item_background**.?? This background is image is failed to load because it is using too much memory.

Comment: Do you have projects_list_item_background drawable in all your drawable folders??

Comment: @Boss It is a simple 1920x1080 picture in the drawable folder.

Comment: @Sajal I have it drawable but I do not have any other drawable folders for specific screen types.

Comment: Thats why OutOfMemory exception is coming because android tries to resize it according to your phone screen type. Please put drawables in all drawables folder. This will solve your outofmemory crash.